# Windows Phone 7 App crashing but not when debugging

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, exception

I'm not really sure how specific I can get. I've noticed this in multiple places in my app. I'm running an app in the Windows Phone 7 emulator and every so often it will just crash. When I run it in debug mode, it does not crash. I haven't been able to attach an Unhandled Exception handler the way I usually do.

```
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
```

Has anyone seen this before? Or at least know how I can attach an Unhandled Exception Handler for WP7? I'm pretty much out of ideas on how to track down what's causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens also on Windows desktop applications, depending on the nature of the crash or how aggressive the corruption has occurred. I think you should divide and conquer, comment out pieces and test if the program crashes or remains running. You get the drill.

Answer (score 0):

Try this article to add error reporting capability to your app. It basically writes out an error log to your app's isolated storage when crashing and displays it when you next start your app.

[Error Reporting on Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx)